# Will we ever be able to understand history with 100% accuracy

Tags: time-travel, ancient-history

Asked the same question on History SE and was directed here.

Link with the context is
[here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/64078/will-we-ever-be-able-to-understand-history-with-100-accuracy)

And this is the question:

First of all, I am not a historian or anything of the like, but this question was bothering me for quite some time.

As far as I understand, the current methodology historians use to explain our history is mostly based on theoreticizing. Like reading certain works some long dead person wrote, digging up certain items etc etc. Can we ever be 100% sure that what we know is a hard truth? (Please correct me if I am wrong)

Let's take hieroglyphics as an example. Are we really certain that our translation of those is correct? What actual proof do we have?

I was reading some mathematical problem out of the Moscow Papyrus and there were still people there that were fighting over what the scribe writing those might have meant.

My question is will we ever achieve such a scientific milestone that we will be able to truly understand for a fact every event in history so we wouldn't have to theoreticize about it and just say what most likely happened?

Comment: Sorry, often other SE communities think that if something doesn't fit their scope it will fit worldbuilding. This is not the case. You are just starting a speculative discussion, not trying to solve a problem with the rules of your world. You can find more info in our [help]

Comment: Given the conversation nature, a history-related subreddit on reddit.com may be a better place to have a discussion and answer your question.

Comment: (1) History is the scientific study of the past. The methodological base of this study is called the [historical method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_method); languages other than English may prefer something like [historical method*ology*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Méthodologie_historique). (2) Yes, we are quite sure that we can read ancient Egyptian texts; the proof that our reading is correct is that it works, that is, that when we read them they make sense. Not different from reading any other language. (continued...)

Comment: (Continued) (3) People are arguing over the meaning of [Hilbert's 4th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_problems): and he was writing in 1900, and in German, which I hope you would agree is a well-known language. (4) In general, history aims for two targets: first, to find out the facts (for example, who did what, where, and when; or what was the price of wheat); and then, why. The difficulties increase as one goes deeper into the past, obviously, up to a point where the historical method stops working completely, and everything that happened before is called *pre*history.

Comment: Perhaps this would fit into philosophy. Linguistics is further advanced than you think it is; linguists have created dictionaries and grammars for languages that are only theoretical (like proto-indo-european, a root language of many current languages); and no, they aren't 100% certain of it because no written records of it exist.